# Instance of found component equals to null using enzyme full mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

I have wizard component which i would like to test.

**WizardComponent**

```
class WizardComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.steps.map(({Component, ...props}) => <Component {...props} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
it('Provides props to the component', () => {
 const FakeComponent = props => <div>1</div>

    const fakeProps = {
        test:1,
        prop4:'test'
    }

    const wrapper = mount(<WizardComponent currentStepName="fakeComponent" steps={[
        {Component:FakeComponent, name:'fakeComponent'},
    ]}/>)

    const component = wrapper.find(FakeComponent);
    console.log(wrapper.contains(<FakeComponent />)) // logs true
    console.log(component) // logs ReactWrapper { length: 1 }
    console.log(component.instance()) // logs null

    expect(component.instance().props).objectContaining(fakeProps)

})
```

Why i can not access the component instance ?I would like to test its children components props.Can someone help?

Comment: u lost } in your component

Comment: Thanks but that did not help.I just made typos writing this demo.The component renders correctly though

Comment: Try `component.props()` instead of `component.instance().props`

Comment: @SamBokai Thanks, that did the trick, i would like to accept your answer if you write one.Also if you can point me why i can not access the instance of the component (and should i?) i would be really happy.Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. The docs say that only the instance of the root component can be accessed. I definitely was able to use `.instance()` in the past.

Comment: I just noticed that youre doing `component.instance()`. It should be `wrapper.instance()` though. Or is this just a typo in your SO post?

Comment: You are right, that is the typo in the demo.Thanks Sam!

Comment: So you're able to access instance now?

Comment: Nope, that was typos in the demo i did not include component variable.I have updated example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [enyzme documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html), props of a component wrapper are accessed using `wrapper.props()`.

You used `wrapper.instance().props`.